# Celery group and chain are very slow when large number of tasks

Tags: python, redis, celery, distributed-computing

We have a job which consist anything from few hundred to few thousands of tasks. Some of this tasks can run in parallel while other needs results of the previous tasks.
Results are save on S3 by worker, so we ignore them here.

Looking at celery docs combination of chain & group gives us the functionality we need... and it works great for a small set of tasks. 
Starting over 1K tasks on a decent laptop with local redis takes over 30s. Run it on something smaller (e.i. aws lambda) and it will take minutes to apply_async().

Any clue on what's so expensive here?

```
from celery import Celery, signature, chain, group
import time

celery = Celery('some_project', broker='redis://redis:6379/0', 
                                task_serializer='json', task_ignore_result=True)

def get_sig():
    return signature('tasks.run_node', queue='default', 
                    immutable=True, kwargs={ 
                        'node_id': 7, 
                        'job_id': 22, 
                        'job_task_id': '#xx, Not too long string',
                        'backend': {
                            'logger_url': 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.yyy/some_url?awdawdawd=awdwadwadawd',
                            'job_details_url': 'https://zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.yyy/some_other_url?ddwczcd=qwdwa'
                        }
                    })

chain_tasks = []                            
chain_tasks.append( get_sig() )
chain_tasks.append( group([ get_sig() for i in range(300) ]) )
chain_tasks.append( get_sig() )
chain_tasks.append( group([ get_sig() for i in range(300) ]) )
chain_tasks.append( get_sig() )
chain_tasks.append( group([ get_sig() for i in range(300) ]) )
chain_tasks.append( get_sig() )
chain_tasks.append( group([ get_sig() for i in range(300) ]) )
chain_tasks.append( get_sig() )
chain_tasks.append( group([ get_sig() for i in range(200) ]) )
chain_tasks.append( get_sig() )
chain_tasks.append( group([ get_sig() for i in range(200) ]) )
chain_tasks.append( get_sig() )

start = time.time()
result = chain(chain_tasks).apply_async()
print(f'took: {str(time.time() - start)}s')
```

```
took: 39.361984968185425s
```

tested ubuntu 18 with python 3.7, celery 4.3 and redis 5

Comment: I am experiencing something similar with `chord` and `.s(...)`